# Sitecore 9.3 Channels and Referring Sites not updated

Tags: experience-analytics

I am using Sitecore 9.3 and when trying to open the site from external social site, user is redirected to identity server for login then redirected back to the site.

when i checked the database i found that the channel id is "Direct" and Referrer site is "".

Is there any configuration needs to be done so that Referrer site and  channel Id set with the values related to the external social source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore will default set the "Direct" channel to the interactions. In two ways we can set the channel.

1. By creating the campaign and have the option to set the channel.
2. Dynamically set the channel of the interaction by extending the "determineInteractionChannel" pipeline. Here is the good article for channel mapping.

https://sitecore.namics.com/2019/08/22/make-channel-allocation-in-sitecore-9-great-again